# Count the number of compositions of \$n\$ in which the greatest part is odd

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, integer-partitions

A composition of an integer \$n\$ is a representation of \$n\$ as a sum of positive integers. For example the eight compositions of 4 are as follows:

```
4, 3 + 1, 1 + 3, 2 + 2, 2 + 1 + 1, 1 + 2 + 1, 1 + 1 + 2, 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.
```

The challenge is to output the number of compositions of \$n\$ in which the greatest part is odd.

The sequence has generating function

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-x)^2 x^{2n-1}}{(1-2x+x^{2n-1}) (1-2x+x^{2n})}$$

You only need to do this for n up to 33.

Your code should output the following numbers in order.

```
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 7
6 14
7 30
8 62
9 129
10 263
11 534
12 1076
13 2160
14 4318
15 8612
16 17145
17 34097
18 67764
19 134638
20 267506
21 531606
22 1056812
23 2101854
24 4182462
25 8327263
26 16588973
27 33066080
28 65945522
29 131588128
30 262702054
31 524699094
32 1048433468
33 2095744336
```

You only need to output the second column, not the first.

The numbers are taken directly from [OEIS A103421](https://oeis.org/A103421) .

Comment: is x the number of compositions?

Comment: Is the output fixed, i.e. always those 33 values?

Comment: @py3programmer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function might be helpful.

Comment: (as opposed to a variable number of values)

Comment: @Neil Ideally you would print out as many as possible but I am only judging based on the first 33.

Comment: Is displaying all 33 numbers before the heat death of the universe a strict requirement? If so, it may not be very well suited for `code-golf`.

Comment: @Arnauld I would definitely prefer that but... because I know people don't like their code to terminate before the heat death of the universe I have not added it as a strict requirement.  It would just be much cooler if it terminated!

Comment: By sequence rules may we take a number as input and print the nth value?

Comment: @mousetail That is fine.

Comment: Check out [tag info for sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info); its default I/O methods have been refined for years. And combined with "theoretically correct answers are ok", "You only need to do this for n up to 33" isn't really meaningful.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 58 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,m=0:sum(f(k,max(m,n-k))for k in range(n))or m%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpBCoMwEEbhvaeYjTADU6gKIoKHSdFUSec3pAr19Kmu3L7vxWObVzRdTDn74ePsNTqC2vDsv7ux56DmfmyKRxDxa6JACyg5vCeGyBmsrPMFuKFSqlrpC4ppwcZQ8tec/w)

An exponential solution that implicitly generates all compositions by deciding at each branch how to split the current value `n` into the first part `n-k` and remaining parts adding to `k`. Tracks the running maximum `m`, and when the initial `n` is exhausted, returns `m%2` to indicate if the maximum part was odd.

---

**60 bytes**

```python
f=lambda n,m=1,r=2:n>1and f(n-1,max(r,m),r+1)+f(n-1,m)or m%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxBCsJADEbhvafIRpjQuEgLIoXxLpE6ttD8HUIXevqxgqsH3@LVzz5vGG41Wit5NX9MRhDPKpH7EXc1TFQSLipu7xTiLNEpd3/jLcjPfStHQQsoDK9nUiG98niiGgv2BPk9mNsX)

An exponential-time solution. Given `n`, it branches through all compositions of `n`, by deciding whether to increment the last summand or append a new summand of 1. Actually, we don't need to keep track of the entire composition, but only:

- `n`, the remaining value left to assign
- `m`, the maximum run length encountered so far
- `r`, the current run length plus one

When we increment the last summand, we bump up the run length and update the maximum to whichever is bigger of the current maximum and the new run length. When we append a new summand of 1, we reset the run length and keep the maximum. If either case, we decrement `n` because we've used up `1` value.

---

**[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 68 bytes**

```python
lambda n:sum(~len(max(f"{k:b}".split('0')))%2for k in range(2**~-n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcrRCoIwFAbg@57iIIjniEUaRAx8k24muRpuv2MuKCJffeFVtx9feKfHjNMlxGz6a3baDzdNUMvT8@pGsNcvNsVnUsO3OCzB2cTVsRKRsjNzpIksKGrcR@7qet1DJG@Ov7cNtWdROwrRIjEaMry1Hw)

A slow exponential-time solution. Generates all \$2^{n-1}\$ compositions by taking all bit strings of length \$n-1\$, splitting on zeroes, taking the length-plus-one of each run of ones, and summing these lengths modulo 2.

Actually, since we only care about the longest run, we just take the max run after splitting, take its length, and flip the parity. And, we can just work with binary representations of numbers from \$0\$ to \$2^{n-1}-1\$ without padding to length \$n-1\$ because the omitted leading zeroes correspond to runs of length 1 which we can ignore.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 92 bytes

```python
g=[17*[1,-1]]
r=range(33)
for i in r:g+=[sum(y[~k:])for*y,k in zip(*g,r)],;print(sum(g[-1]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3Y9Jtow3NtaINdXQNY2O5imyLEvPSUzWMjTW50vKLFDIVMvMUiqzStW2ji0tzNSqj67KtYjWBMlqVOtkguarMAg2tdJ0izVgd64KizLwSDZC69GigaZqaEDugVsGsBAA)

Prints 33 terms.

#### How?

First computes g(n,k), the number of compositions of n with all terms <= k.

This satisfies g(n,k) = g(n-1,k) + ... + g(n-k,k). (Split the set of compositions into k subsets by the size of the first term.)
Once we have those we can compute the odd-largest-term ones as f(n,2k+1) = g(n,1) - g(n,2) + ... + g(n,2k+1).

#### [Python](https://www.python.org), 114 bytes

```python
n,*g=0,
while 1:g+=[sum([p[j]for p in g[~j:]if p[j:]]+g[~j][:j])for j in range(n)]+[1],;print(sum(g[n][::2]));n+=1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3i_J0tNJtDXS4yjMyc1IVDK3StW2ji0tzNaILorNi0_KLFAoUMvMU0qPrsqxiM9MUgKJWsbHaIH5stFVWrCZISRZISVFiXnqqRp5mrHa0YayOdUFRZl6JBsik9Og8oFIro1hNTes8bVtDiM1QB8AcAgA)

Prints forever. Not very golfy but reasonably fast (O(n<sup>3</sup>)). Times out on ato after printing >800 terms.

Comment: This is very impressive!

Comment: @solid.py The semicolon just separates statements. The trailing comma creates a tuple which we add to g. list += works like list.extend. We therefore need the extra level of nesting to preserve the inner list.

Comment: @loopywalt Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Åœ€œ€`Ù€àÉO
```

-4 bytes outputting the \$n^{th}\$ value instead of mapping over the ranged list \$[1,33]\$
Outputs as a list.

Very slow, and will time out for \$n\geq9\$ on TIO.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOvRyY@a1oCJhMMzgeThBYc7/f//NwMA) or [(don't) verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9s7HNu6//DrUcnP2paAyYSDs8EkocXHO70//8fAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Åœ          #  Get all unique lists of positive integers that sum to the (implicit) input
  €œ        #  Get the permutations of each list
    €`      #  Flatten the list of lists of lists by one level
      Ù     #  Uniquify the list of lists
       €à   #  Only leave the maximum of each list
         É  #  Check for each integer whether it's odd
          O #  Sum all those together
            # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)
```

---

A faster version that outputs all values in ~3 seconds on TIO - **18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**:
Port of [*@Jonathan Allan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252135/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

```python
ÅœʒθÉ}εÅγygš!.»÷}O
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//8OFxZPKks64w4l9zrXDhc6zeWfFoSEuwrvDt31P//82) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9vc2FiaWX/MzNMzrX/w4XFk8qSzrjDiX3OtcOFzrN5Z8WhIS7Cu8O3fU///w).

**Explanation:**

```python
Åœ            # Same as above: all positive integer lists that sum to the input
  ʒ           # Filter this list of lists by:
   θ          #  Only leave the last/largest integer
    É         #  And check whether it's odd
  }ε          # After the filter: map over the remaining lists:
    Åγ        #  Run-length encode the list, pushing the list of items and list of
              #  lengths separately to the stack
      y       #  Push the current list again
       g      #  Pop and push its length
        š     #  Prepend this to the list of run-length encoded lengths
         !    #  Get the factorial of each
          .»  #  Left-reduce this list by:
            ÷ #   Integer-dividing
   }O         # After the map: sum everything together
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Manages to do the first 9. The challenge now is to do all 33.

Comment: @graffe Given enough time and memory, it will output all 33 eventually when running the program locally. For codegolf challenge it's enough to work in theory, and warnings/time/O-complexity/etc. are all irrelevant if it can save bytes. If it's mandatory to output all 33 result in a certain amount of time, e.g. within 60 seconds in an online compiler like TIO, the challenge should be changed and need a [restricted-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/restricted-time/info) tag.. :/ But I'll see if I can find a fast enough alternative that outputs all 33 on TIO.

Comment: I know the rules. I was just expressing what I thought would be very cool.

Comment: @graffe Ah ok. :) I'll see if I can find a solution that works a lot faster, perhaps by using your generator function. 

Comment: you can remove the `33Lε` since the OP clarified that taking an integer as input is fine.

Comment: @Steffan Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Well done for speeding it up so much!

Comment: @graffe Well, all credit goes to _Jonathan Allan_, since I basically just ported his answer from Jelly to 05AB1E.

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 machine code, 27 bytes

```
31 C9 48 0F AB F9 6A 01 58 99 89 CF 41 F7 D2 8D 34 3F 21 F7 75 F7 29 D0 E2 EF C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVFBT/MwDD03v8IUTSTrNm2AOGyMC2cu3wmJcUiTtA3KkpG0kIH4619xuk0IfHDkZ/v52RHTWoi@P9dWmE4quA2t1G7W3JFfkNHlX8xrWyeMaNtCRZPnbEV42AKFfzkls9q4khuoSLXMovOgRJwkR7KyDeBT5KUm2a4LDSxWsHM78DwSZ5aZkK8k27o3UFIfm2blvlUwj9cLorHCuhaTiBvFQQWsekI2KBLnM8m4lcfegCNe7AdoQ7LQlaB4kjF0OpzoEPaqJSwHlD9ss@XaHhbytZiAaLiH8RiDN0Y@CaClZIQ1TBcT2OM7Xw3we6ONAloUEW7XsLhkA5psh@dqK5qPNEzvYKQ3Np8A6qhoZOzQfCrZ2AcuGm0VCCfVMj@m488Y6eDzVA2j@eUjcu3XlHY26NoqOSges4o9xaJ4Zquvk7A9nCFJvL/6MxIo6krnDewg7JTv2kRFLzb24gjhqTpvk5Iv0vf/RWV4Hfrp9uYaHX7@GhmV@QY)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes a value in EDI and returns a value in EAX.

The value taken is 0-indexed, so `n-1`, as permitted in the default [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) rules. (For a version taking `n`, insert `dec edi` at the start for +2 bytes.)

In assembly:

```
f:  xor ecx, ecx    # Set ECX to 0.
    bts rcx, rdi    # Set to 1 the bit at position given by the argument.
    push 1; pop rax # Set EAX to 1.
ol: cdq             # Set EDX to 0 by sign-extending EAX.
    mov edi, ecx    # Copy the value of ECX into EDI.
    .byte 0x41      # REX.B prefix; combines with the next instruction
                    #  into "not r10", here effectively a no-op.
il: not edx         # Invert each bit of EDX, changing 0 to -1 or vice versa.
    lea esi, [rdi + rdi]    # Set ESI to 2*EDI.
    and edi, esi    # Bitwise-AND EDI with the doubled value.
    jnz il          # Jump back, to repeat the inner loop, if it's nonzero.
    sub eax, edx    # Subtract EDX from EAX.
                    # This adds 1 from EDX=-1 or is no change for EDX=0.
    loop ol         # Decrease ECX by 1, and jump back if it's nonzero.
    ret             # Return.
```

---

```
1 + 3 + 1  + 4    = 9
● ●—●—● ● ●—●—●—●
 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
```

A composition can be visualised as `n` dots, with each two consecutive dots either joined or not joined.
Then, it can be represented by `n-1` bits, with each bit being 1 for joining or 0 for not joining.
The greatest part is equal to 1 plus the maximum number of consecutive 1s in those bits.

```
Original:       0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
Doubled:      0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
Bitwise AND:    0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

Take the bitwise AND with the value doubled: this reduces the length of each block of consecutive 1s by 1.
Repeat until the result is 0; the number of repetitions is the maximum number of consecutive 1s.

The program loops from \$2^{n-1}\$ down to 1, and counts the compositions with the greatest part odd in EAX. \$2^{n-1}\$ is actually invalid, but it doesn't matter because it doesn't get counted.

0, which corresponds to the composition \$1 + \cdots + 1\$, is skipped because of the way the loop works (but it would have been a false negative anyway, because the inner loop always executes at least once). To correct for this, EAX is initialised to 1 instead of 0.

Because of the use of 32-bit registers for the calculation, when `n=33`, the first iteration uses a value of 0 instead of 2<sup>32</sup>, but this makes no difference to the result.

Comment: Makes it all the way to 32 before timing out.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [m90](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104752/m90)*

```javascript
f=(n,m,i=1)=>i>n?!n&m:f(n-i,i<m?m:i)+f(n,m,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBCoMwEEDRvaeYgpQMiYUUulGjVzFYU6aYiWjpJuTsMeDuLx7/a//2mHfafg2H95KzM4KVV2Q0moEGHm98960T3JCi3o@@JZTuMlJjdmEXDAZ0Bwy9geerhJQIsQKYAx9hXR5r@IjJijpywmLrWAaYJuyqlE8)

(limited to the 25 first terms on TIO)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (         // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,          //   n = input
  m,          //   m = maximum value in the composition
  i = 1       //   i = value to be subtracted from n
) =>          //
i > n ?       // if i is greater than n:
  !n &        //   increment the final result if n = 0
  m           //   and m is odd
:             // else:
  f(          //   do a 1st recursive call where:
    n - i,    //     i is subtracted from n
    i < m ? m //     m is updated to max(m, i)
          : i //     (and i is implicitly reseted to 1)
  ) +         //   end of recursive call
  f(          //   do a 2nd recursive call where:
    n,        //     n is left unchanged
    m,        //     m is left unchanged
    i + 1     //     i is incremented
  )           //   end of recursive call
```

Comment: Your code gets to 28 on TIO ! https://tio.run/##JYxBCsMgEADvecUeQnHRlNpTMTH5SiSNZUtcS1JyEd9uhR4G5jDM253uWHb6fDuOz7UUbwWroMhqtCNPVLkZL7gjRUOYgiGU/p9IjSZcdPFxFwwWdA8Mg4X7o4qUCKkBWCIfcVuvW3yJ2Yk2ccbatqlOMM/YN7n8AA  Not far to go....  (Would the code benefit from memoization?)

Comment: @graffe Yup. Computing a(33) takes a little more than 2 minutes on my laptop, which is quite significantly before the heat death of the universe after all. :-p

Comment: We hope it stays that way!

Comment: 47: `f=(n,m,i=1)=>i>n?m&!n:f(n-i,i<m?m:i)+f(n,m,i+1)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 by delaying the mod-2 check like [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)'s [05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252128/53748).

```
ŒṗŒ!€ẎQṀ€ḂS
```

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer and yields the number of compositions with an odd largest part.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7px@dpPioac3DXX2BD3c2gFg7moL///9vAQA)** (Slow - [\$9\$ within \$1\$ minute on TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7pz/c0fRw5yqVY@1HJyk@alrzcFdfoM9/y8PtQPZ/AA))

Or, a faster version which can do all \$33\$ in [under \$12\$ seconds on TIO](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//xZLhuZfCtUw7xZLJoCE6L8OX4biC4bmqKVP/MzPDh@KCrP8) in \$15\$ bytes (slightly slower than the \$16\$ byte version in the history of edits):

```
ŒṗµL;Œɠ!:/×ḂṪ)S
```

#### How?

The slow one:

```
ŒṗŒ!€ẎQṀ€ḂS - Link: positive integer, n   e.g. 5
Œṗ          - integer partitions          [[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,2],[1,4],[2,3],[5]]
  Œ!€       - all permutations of each    [[[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],...],[[1,1,3],[1,3,1],[1,1,3],[1,3,1],[3,1,1],[3,1,1]],...,[[5]]
     Ẏ      - tighten                     [[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],...,[1,1,3],[1,3,1],[1,1,3],[1,3,1],[3,1,1],[3,1,1],...,[5]]
      Q     - deduplicate                 [[1,1,1,1,1],...,[1,1,3],[1,3,1],[3,1,1],...,[5]]
       Ṁ€   - maximum of each             [1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,4,4,3,3,5]
         Ḃ  - modulo 2                    [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]
          S - sum                         7
```

The faster version calculates the number of distinct permutations for each partition and sums them up instead:

```
ŒṗµL;Œɠ!:/×ḂṪ)S - Link: positive integer, n
Œṗ              - all partitions
                  (note: each are always in sorted order)
  µ          )  - for each: e.g. part = [2,2,2,4,5,5]
   L            -   length               6
     Œɠ         -   run-lengths         [3,1,2]
    ;           -   concatenate         [6,3,1,2]
       !        -   factorial           [720,6,1,2]
         /      -   reduce by:
        :       -     integer division   60
           Ḃ    -   (part) modulo 2     [0,0,0,0,1,1]
          ×     -   multiply            [0,0,0,0,60,60]
            Ṫ   -   tail                 60
              S - sum
```

Comment: This makes a very good advert for Jelly.

Comment: Porting Kevin's 05AB1E answer is [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7px@dpPioac3DXX2BD3c2gFg7moL///9vDgA "Jelly – Try It Online").

Comment: Thanks, @Steffan - the same idea applied to the faster version saves a byte and makes it slower but only by a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

## Regex  ([RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/) / PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35+</sup></sub>), 45 bytes

```
^(?*(x(xx)*))(?(?=\1(x*))x+(?=\3($)?)|x+)+$\4
```

Takes its input in unary, as the length of a string of `x`s. Returns its output as the number of ways the regex can match. (The rabbit emoji indicates this output method.)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbNbttGED4W0FOsmdTeJalUlNvAEE0Lri3ABhI7UGQ0jawSNLmUFqGWBLmMZTe-5gF67aWH9pgHSo99jV46-yOJtgSUsKT9mfnm75uhf_8SF1ldyU84jeMvY6udFXFJu-0Da_J1-CyhKeMUvTkZDrrhyeXpILy6OB-FP52fjs7QQesZ43FWJxQdKqUXs6NWPItKFBbjCQrQ0Prx9vbDzX79893du9Hs5e0M_1WLtH3wtf0L7tt4gRcLYhOC-7gfXHt4AeuFI9f7-Dnpk08LhzjPr7_XSn9_8y95ime5yC6CsHA8v-FMJUrGp9Kb9RnL4ZRG86MNuaMW4wIVsBQhLcu8xHHOK4FUJPacVlU0pQT9Womk14tBAh0eInMsl-qc8iTzUUlFXXLk-Q8bmHIf5wl10U2eZygP0iirJKwyY-DG3R9eTvwWgoelCKukhlNqMEIjhTUO1lW5Ojk7Hh7YxFy6qGL3NE_xyvHvlicNeUKIsiIfnKO-DiLOa4F6aBUokeFZSg0pD3rIehK8UrYs0LKuuUVW-UiBUTMdySoprYdWzSs25TRBWc6n-ivi1S0tfZWw-V0YR1kGbpjYzS68yfL4A7JjF33MWYLsJBIR5E4mSS5RECAsb2yyu8YgBttxVpXpmMrMI8YxACgHizEQIaMcF6TtTYKOr0PQ7EBFHFi437N8WDlBoX8s4OwJfHYInNeAuN8NBRQVdCX8FBYKugnEeFELqa4CgxIiu6TL_TwS8SxUsdjrtUYraVVnwtUl8E0zvj1_P1AnaVpRuIR4IYSpmD0SsPOPNBagZSoBTbm0Py9YRrEhxds3oyEp4hdxCM5i4hqM94PhZTgaDF-fXxyPBqfL48G70eDiVO53lU_m13jSIWsG75RAQJP7ZjeobyPXCD3YyEYI-0jQMC3zeVhEQtCS4xJYfnH16pUBaOpA6wq6EJDE5SrYdm9g8QYKRLCi4BLCbfDS3cazpwDaVMbmrAnS9ojfEEpoIf5XqKRxXVYs51sFldk0L5GaLvcr5sLEyGBsY93IjLuae8RfMl6VB1R4B9ITiZxhJbAsP9Sfey4q8gqu9Q28BhK8194zRuXDPZlbkNkJmjzv9bg87G_BRY6Sd5BHYGDwzhpLz1ppjtNbvRtzz_EmPgybOWQCVy7aW-xJxyBBFVxOgob-Kgks4LIHDwPu-chxWDPiJSnvCQKnpBG8d80hJEgdSCt-ptj6NkH_fP4NwauFwZUeIeBYw5ruJdmUj9mliNnsKHCaQUOovzWnYW3KSPwN5zTuYQft7hobO4HpuuHwchheXL4-Hp2ckUeKin6N9lpODFHW9IkNCm-dDd319If5bSLeMsnl89Baf29rrLSkFK_j22xoLbDak-ZE1JcwM1YDW0cCrw79P8Aff3ba3Y5e_wc) - PCRE2 v10.40+
[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Unordered-partitions-with-odd-greatest) - RegexMathEngine

```
^               # tail = input number
(?*
    (x(xx)*)    # \1 = {any odd number, which shall be the maximum
                        partition width}
)
(?(?=
    \1(x*)      # \3 = tail - \1
  )
    # If the above condition (tail ≥ \1) is true:
    x+          # tail -= {any positive number}
    (?=\3($)?)  # Assert tail ≥ \3; if tail == \3, set \4 = 0
|
    # Else:
    x+          # tail -= {any positive number}
)+              # Iterate the above any positive number of times
$               # Assert tail == 0
\4              # Assert that \4 is set, i.e. that the chosen maximum
                # partition width occurred at least once.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
ṄvṖÞfUvG∷∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBUCIsIiIsIuG5hHbhuZbDnmZVdkfiiLfiiJEiLCIiLCIxXG4yXG4zXG40XG41XG42XG43Il0=)

Port of 05AB1E. Very slow.

```
ṄvṖÞfUvG∷∑   # example input: 3
Ṅ            # integer partitions => [[1, 1, 1], [2, 1], [3]]
 vṖ          # permutations of each => [[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[2, 1], [1, 2]], [[3]]]
   Þf        # flatten by one level => [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3]]
     U       # uniquify => [[1, 1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3]]
      vG     # max of each => [1, 2, 2, 3]
        ∷    # modulo each by 2 => [1, 0, 0, 1]
         ∑   # sum => 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

No integer partitions in Japt but a port of [xnor's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252147/58974) works out at a respectable length. Completes for input `33`, and beyond, in milliseconds.

```
ÆßXVwXnUÃx ªVu
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xt9YVndYblXDeCCqVnU&input=MzM)

```
ÆßXVwXnUÃx ªVu     :Implicit input of integers U and V, the latter of which defaults to 0
Æ                  :Map each X in the range [0,U)
 ßX                :  Recursive call with arguments X and
   Vw              :    Max of V and
     XnU           :      U-X
        Ã          :End map
         x         :Reduce by addition
           ª       :Logical OR with
            Vu     :V%2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 121 bytes

```
f(n)=1+∑_{k=1}^{n^n-1}0^{(n-total(AL))^2+mod(L[A>0].max-1,2)}A.total!/∏_{i=1}^nA![i]
L=[1...n]
A=mod(floor(nk/n^L),n)
```

What can I say, Desmos just isn't that great at problems involving counting partitions, especially ones where order matters.

Also, this is very inefficient. It can't even calculate \$n=10\$ in a reasonable amount of time, let alone \$n=33\$. This is because it tests \$n^n-1\$ different partitions; as you can imagine, that is not efficient at all.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/obvcdwg9la)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lfuq9nuq0v)

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 425 bytes:

```py
import math as M,itertools as I
R=range
Y=lambda x:x[0]if 1==len(x)else x[0]*Y(x[1:])
def f(n,s,c):
 if n==0:yield c;return
 for i in{*R(1,s+1)}-{*c}:
  for x in R(1,n//i+1):
   if i*x<=n:yield from f(n-i*x,s,c+[i]*x)
def F(n):
 t=[]
 for i in R(1,n+1):
  if i%2:t+=[tuple(sorted(j))for k in R(1,n//i+1)for j in f(n-i*k,i,[i]*k)]
 return sum(M.factorial(len(j))/Y([M.factorial(len([*b]))for _,b in I.groupby(j)])for j in{*t})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHLbsIwEEXXzVd4U8l2zCOliyqtt0gs2LBDVlTl4YAhsSPbkYIQ3556CKISS9@ZOffOuLv4o9Grr86Oo2o7Yz1qc39EuUNbpry03pjGwXMT7bjN9UFGe97kbVHlaEgHscxUjRLOG6nxQGTjJAKR7vEgkjQjUSVrVGPNHCtJGqHQrTlfphclmwqV31b63uoI1cYihZS@0h1OmIsTcptdaXkLI/faEGoISnqxUKEKOsAUHX64fuBqa1owmwUVDGOhMjpMGdZYw5DnIvt3m4gPHNDeP1Ifc@H7rpHYhXPICp8Igf7zSwLQTqBNhmemGNidSeBPWyHXt3g7r/PSG6vyBsORAm2xx@JVFrTIJp9fVgB1Mz9Y03fFJUxkT7Mr9TcyPuPfPyREWn2GDd46q7THiq2xImT8Aw)

Prints all 33 results in ~10 seconds.

Comment: Ooh this is great! How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 52 bytes

-13 bytes thanks to [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor).

```
n->sum(i=0,2*n,(-1)^i*(1-x)/(1-2*x+x^i))%x^(n+1)\x^n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN03ydO2KS3M1Mm0NdIy08nQ0dA014zK1NAx1KzT1gaSRVoV2RVympqZqRZxGnrahZkxFXB5Ur0pafpFGnoKtgqGOgqmBjkJBUWZeCVBASUHXDkikaeRpampC1C5YAKEB)

Using the generating function.

Comment: [52 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN03ydO2KS3M1Mm0NdIy08nQ0dA014zK1NAx1KzT1gaSRVoV2RVympqZqRZxGnrahZkxFXB5Ur0pafpFGnoKtgqGOgqmBjkJBUWZeCVBASUHXDkikaeRpampC1C5YAKEB) with a different g.f. formula I found.

Comment: And the `2*n` can be `34` for -1 byte since the challenge only requires it work up to `n=33`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 42 bytes

```
Mod[Max@## 2^#,2]+#0[#-i,##2,i]~Sum~{i,#}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zc/Jdo3scJBWVnBKE5ZxyhWW9kgWlk3U0dZ2UgnM7YuuDS3rhrIq1X7H1CUmVcClLNLc1COVatzLCpKrKwzNv4PAA)

Slow recursive solution.

Comment: Are you able to try Rest[ CoefficientList[ Series[ Expand[ Sum[(1 - x)^2*x^(2n - 1)/((1 - 2x + x^(2n - 1))*(1 - 2x + x^(2n))), {n, 35}]], {x, 0, 35}], x]] ? I wondered how fast it is.

Comment: @graffe [see for yourself](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P7g0N1rDULdCM85IH0gbVWhXxOVpVsTp6uYh8bX9HSrijE10qvN0jHTMLHSMamOjo411lGNj1f4HFGXmlUQr69qlOSjHqtU5FhUlVtYZG/8HAA)

Comment: Wow, that’s fast!

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), (slow) 16 bytes

```
cn od<xMl<<pt<e1
```

**Alternative 1**

```
cn(od<xMl)<pt<e1
```

**Alternative 2**

```
l<pST(od<xMl)<e1
```

### Explanation

- `e1`: Create a list from \$1\$ to \$n\$.
- `pt`: Get all partitions of the list.
- `xMl<`: Get the length of the largest part in each partition.
- `cn od`: Count the number of odd results.

### Reflection

I've not spent much focus on arithmetic in hgl, so I am pretty pleased with this. The use of `xMl` here is brutally efficient. That being said there are some things I think could be improved.

- There's no function which takes mod 2.  You can do `fmu 2`, but that's really long.  Small modulos should have builtins.  This wouldn't make this answer shorter, but I noticed this.
- There should be a function for finding integer partitions.  `l<<pt<e1` is *way* too long, and this will likely come up again.  With a function for integer partitions, `ipt`, this whole thing could be `cn od<mx<<ipt` which would save 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 31 bytes

```apl
{2+.|⌈/¨∪((∨\⍢⌽⍵=+\)¨⊆⍥∊⊢)⍳⍴⍨⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P03hUdsEhWojbb2aRz0d@odWPOpYpaHxqGNFzKPeRY969j7q3WqrHaMJFO9qe9S79FFH16OuRZqPejc/6t3yqHcFULr2/6O@qWBT0hQMuRBsIyS2MRLbBIltisQ24/oPAA)

```apl
    ⍳⍴⍨ all permutations of 1..n
      (∨\⍢⌽⍵=+\)¨ mask contiguous subsets which compose to n
        ⊆⍥∊ partition compositions
    ∪ uniques
    ⌈/¨ greatest of each
    2+.| count odds
```

Same length in BQN: `` {+´2|0⌈´¨⍷⥊(∨`⌾⌽=+`)⊸/¨1+↕⥊˜} ``

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
ＩＥφＬΦＥＸφφ↨λφ∧⌊λ∧⁼⊕ιΣλ﹪⌈λ²
```

Don't try it online, or indeed offline, because it needs unreasonable amounts of time and memory. Instead, here's a link that computes 6 values instead:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PUzLCgIhFP0Vl1cw6AGzaVVRECQM9AWil0a4XstH9fcmw9BZnbedTLLRUGtj8lzgZHIBbZ4wKHFDfpQJLp4Kptkc46eznRKbtVTiaDICKTHILg7sQHv2oQagRZ9f1VCGK9uEAbmgA9@j@1zpREdXKfbn73@2lQv2rbXVm34) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  φ                         Predefined variable `1000`
 Ｅ                          Map over implicit range
       φ                    Predefined variable `1000`
      Ｘ                     Raised to power
        φ                   Predefined variable `1000`
     Ｅ                      Map over implicit range
          λ                 Current value
         ↨                  Converted to base
           φ                Predefined variable `1000`
    Φ                       Filtered where
              λ             List of base `1000` digits
             ⌊              Minimum
            ∧               Logical And
                  ι         Outer value
                 ⊕          Incremented
                ⁼           Equals
                    λ       List of base `1000` digits
                   Σ        Summed
               ∧            Logical And
                       λ    List of base `1000` digits
                      ⌈     Maximum
                     ﹪      Modulo
                        ²   Literal integer `2`
   Ｌ                        Take the length
Ｉ                           Cast to string
                            Implicitly print
```

36 bytes for a slightly faster version:

```
⊞υ⟦⁰⟧ＦυＦ⁻φΣι⊞υ⁺ι⟦⊕κ⟧ＩＥφＬΦυ∧⁼⊕ιΣλ﹪⌈λ²
```

Don't try it online, because it still tries to compute 1,000 values. Instead, here's a link that computes 10 values instead:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwDIbvPkWPCUyYXncSURA2GHiUHcpWXTBrtW3Et691QzCXhD/5vvSj9r3TnFIrYQQp1KXssFpdnVcgqObekJUAm7JQZ5mAEFH9rlvOG8rUyfbeTMZGM8AdO8yO1pONsNchQqMfM18be4sjHImj8V9@Zwc4PEVzgH8D4fKLMQ@NG4RddrxpmrNCbXGpKqW0fvEH) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦⁰⟧
```

Start with a sum of `0`.

```
Ｆυ
```

Loop over all of the sums so far.

```
Ｆ⁻φΣι
```

Find integers to add to this sum without exceeding 1,000.

```
⊞υ⁺ι⟦⊕κ⟧
```

Add the new sum to the list of sums.

```
ＩＥφＬΦυ∧⁼⊕ιΣλ﹪⌈λ²
```

Count how many sums with odd maxima sum to each integer up to 1,000.

42 bytes for a slightly faster still version:

```
Ｆφ⊞υＥφ⎇κ⎇›κι⁰Σ⁺…§υ±κκＥ…⮌υκ§μκ¬ιＩＥΦυκΣΦι﹪μ²
```

Don't try it online, because it still tries to compute 999 values. Instead, here's a link that computes 9 values instead:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BDoIwDIbvPsWOXYKJeuVkSDQeNER9gQWqLAxGuo3I089VMPTUv/3/r60aRZVVJsaXJQH7nRRlcA2ETFzVkHQmnki9ognatT0TKo/EIy0zkUyP0EFpgoNiqgwWjR3g6C99jR9G3fCd/NDKZG7ljF6NdxyRHEJYtv9gx5IrAawHzW2@KUn3HgrlPDDmpA1/EuYov7FMdDpj62Ascw4/jsxjjNvRfAE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆφ
```

Loop 1,000 times.

```
⊞υＥφ⎇κ⎇›κι⁰Σ⁺…§υ±κκＥ…⮌υκ§μκ¬ι
```

Calculate the matrix `f(n, m)` of the number of sums of compositions of `n` whose maximum is `m`. The "first" row for `n=0` is simply `1, 0...` and subsequent rows are calculated by moving up `m` cells and left `m` cells and summing the passed-over cells.

```
ＩＥΦυκΣΦι﹪μ²
```

For each `n>0`, sum those `f(n, m)` where `m` is odd.

Example: The first few rows of `f` look like this:

```
1   0   ...
-----------
0   1   0   ...
--------------+
0   1   1   0 | ...
----------+   |
0   1   2 | 1 | 0 | ...
------+   |   |   |
0   1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 | ...
--+   |   |   |   |   |
0 | 1 | 7 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 | ...
```

These are calculated as `1 = 1 + 0`, `7 = 4 + 2 + 1 + 0`, `5 = 2 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0`, `2 = 1 + .... + 1 + 0`, `1 = ... + 1`.

This final version can be adapted to calculate exactly 33 values, but that takes 44 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCsIwDIbvPkWPKUwQ9baTDBQPylBfoMzoyrp1pO1wT18bN1lO@ZP//5KqVlRZZWJ8WRKw20tRBldDyMRF9Uln4oHUKRqhWdoTofJIPNIyE5tM3EMLpQkOirEyWNS2h4M/d0/8MOqK7@SHRiZzIyf0YrzhgOQQwrz9B1uWXAlgPWhu81VJuvNQKOeBMUdt@JMwRfmNeaLTGfsMxjJn@@PIPMa4HswX) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
sm&%ed2l{.pd./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfjvFhgc@L84V001NcUop1qvIEVP//9/y3/5BSWZ@XnF/3VTAA)

### Explanation

```
sm&%ed2l{.pd./Q
s                  # sum(
 m                 #   map(
                   #     lambda d:
   %ed2            #       (d[-1] % 2)
  &                #         and  # short-circuiting
       l{.pd       #       len(unique(permutations(d)),
            ./Q    #     partitions(input)  # partitions are sorted
                   #   )
                   # )
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), (slow) 49 bytes

```haskell
0!u=mod u 2
x!u=sum[(x-i)!max u i|i<-[1..x]]
```

```
(!0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgFEXRuat4znSQVONcQisQCaGiT/2SSnDQ3q1ml8NdwrVO21ZKLZPlY0RCK/LXV2KnckVacsif0kNd5RpjsvditkrWunCgHRbjIQAOsR@g4kn7DYNZ45@b1pcX)